# in Laravel 4, i can't create data in another connection

Tags: php, laravel

the code can't create data

```
UserToken::on('user')->create($token_data);
```

result:{"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::create()","file":"F:\web\vgooo_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php","line":2094}}

and i try another code

```
$UserToken = new UserToken();
DB::connection('user')->table($UserToken->getTable())->insert($token_data);
```

result: success

why i  can't use the "on" , is a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Laravel source for [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L605):

```
/**
 * Begin querying the model on a given connection.
 *
 * @param  string  $connection
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public static function on($connection = null)
{
    // First we will just create a fresh instance of this model, and then we can
    // set the connection on the model so that it is be used for the queries
    // we execute, as well as being set on each relationship we retrieve.
    $instance = new static;

    $instance->setConnection($connection);

    return $instance->newQuery();
}
```

Your `on()` call returns an `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` but the `create()` method you are trying to call is only available in the Eloquent's `Model` class.

You can do this instead:

```
$user = new UserToken;
$user->setConnection('user');
$user->create($token_data);
```

Or do it the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#inserts) way:

```
UserToken::on('user')->insert($token_data);
```

Comment: uh... the second throw exception too, the third can run but available the $timestamp . i want to use method from eloquent

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'news.user_tokens' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `user_tokens` (`user_id`, `token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (63575, d845b1d0c2d40e6701415deadc7f786d, 1403332385, 1403332385))

Comment: It's saying you don't have the table user_tokens in your database. Maybe the other database you are connecting to doesn't have it?